# libcurl use same user defined port to send periodic request

Tags: c++, curl, https, port, libcurl

I am working on a project need to send periodic alive message to https server.

Because of security issue, we need to use minimal number of ports (blocking unused ports as many as we can).

I am using c++ libcurl easy interface to send https request in linux.

I have tried to use the same curl handler object (CURL object) and set CURLOPT_LOCALPORT to a port number. The first request is ok. But in the second,  libcurl verbose mode said address already in use.
However, when I comment out the port set through CURLOPT_LOCALPORT, it works on second connection also, and by setting VERBOSE to 1, I can see "Re-using existing connection" print out, which is missing in version setting up local port.
And I check with linux netstat, find out that it is using the same port.
I cannot figure out why setting up local port will make it failed.

And also, I have tried to close the connection using curl_easy_cleanup, but due to tcp time_wait state, we cannot reuse the port in a while, that's not what I want.

Could anyone provide a solution or suggestion to us? Thanks a lot.

**Edit**
My reason using one port is not to keep opening and closing connection too much.

Answer (score 1):

> Because of the security issue ...

There is no security issue. You need to get over this phobia about using multiple local outbound ports. There is zero security benefit in using fewer, or in constraining them in any way.

Comment: Sorry for my poor sentence, my main reason using one port for the periodic message is the concern about opening and closing a connection in periodic request using libcurl may causing some overhead, resources problem.
And keep opening and closing a connection seems not a good idea.

Comment: A resources problem such as what? Do you actually *have* a problem? Or are you just guessing?